# Recommended MySQL Data Type and Size for PayPal IPN Transaction Database

Tags: mysql, paypal-ipn

I am working on (or rather, improving) an application that utilizes PayPal IPN. It records the transaction data to a MySQL database.

The actual recording of the data is no problem.  However, I cannot find any information on the recommended data type and size for each possible value.

Here is what I am presently using (taken from the query creating the table):

```
$create_transaction_table = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " . $wpdb->prefix . "paypal_transactions (
        id BIGINT(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
        user_id BIGINT(20) NOT NULL,
        timestamp DATETIME NOT NULL ,
        payment_date         VARCHAR(30),
        receiver_email       VARCHAR(60),
        item_name            VARCHAR(100),
        item_number          VARCHAR(10),
        payment_status       VARCHAR(10),
        pending_reason       VARCHAR(10),
        mc_gross             VARCHAR(20),
        mc_fee               VARCHAR(20),
        tax                  VARCHAR(20),
        mc_currency          VARCHAR(10),
        txn_id               VARCHAR(30),
        txn_type             VARCHAR(10),
        transaction_subject  VARCHAR(50),
        first_name           VARCHAR(30),
        last_name            VARCHAR(40),
        address_name         VARCHAR(50),
        address_street       VARCHAR(50),
        address_city         VARCHAR(30),
        address_state        VARCHAR(30),
        address_zip          VARCHAR(20),
        address_country      VARCHAR(30),
        address_country_code VARCHAR(10),
        residence_country    VARCHAR(10),
        address_status       VARCHAR(10),
        payer_email          VARCHAR(60),
        payer_status         VARCHAR(10),
        payment_type         VARCHAR(10),
        payment_gross        VARCHAR(20),
        payment_fee          VARCHAR(20),
        notify_version       VARCHAR(10),
        verify_sign          VARCHAR(10),
        referrer_id          VARCHAR(10),
        business             VARCHAR(60),
        ipn_track_id         VARCHAR(20)
    )";
```

To clarify my question, what I'm looking for is information on recommended types (obviously, I'm using varchar) and size.  In initial testing, this seems to be OK, but I had a previous process that ended up with some truncated data because the field was too short. However, I don't want to go the other direction and make them all "200".

Does anyone know what the recommended field sizes are?

Comment: looking in to [Sample IPN Message and Response](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNIntro/#a-sample-ipn-message-and-response) i would most likely convert those messages to JSON, for some reason a fixed RDMS model does not seams to be suited.. And only store the data which always has the "predicatable" format for example the transaction id's .. indexing also does not have to be trouble assuming you are using a MySQL version with native JSON and generated columns support.

Comment: Note that the number in parentheses after an integer data type is essentially meaningless.